# Jetpack Compose - inherit hosting app's theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an Android SDK that starts an Activity when being invoked. The Activity needs to inherit the same Theme as hosting app, i.e it's action bar, button, text needs to have same colors with the hosting app.

This is easily achievable with traditional XML views by declaring the SDK's Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` *without* a `theme`, then it will inherit whatever theme the host app has.

But it seems no longer possible in Jetpack Compose - it seems the `Composable`s will always have the default purple colors even not being wrapped inside a `MaterialTheme`.

Is it possible to get the hosting app's theme for Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Wrap your composables in a `MdcTheme` like the following code snippets hows:

```
 setContent {
       MdcTheme {
           YourComposable()
       }
 }
```

This will apply your legacy style system.